# How to expose HTTP port on azure VM

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, azure, cloud

I am trying to expose port 7445 on my azure VM (Windows server 2008) for **HTTP (not HTTPS)** requests, I have added an inbound rule for this port still cant access it. Dose any one have idea what I am doing wrong? below is the screen shot of my inbound port rule

> I have tried with different priorities also,
>   I am trying to access the spring boot api running on this VM through POSTMAN

[image] [image]

Comment: Is there a network security group attached to the subnet as well? Is it definitely listening on that port, i.e. can you connect on localhost when connected to the server? Is there a policy on any software firewall on the server itself?

Answer (score 1):

This will be one or more of the below:

- There is an NSG at the subnet level as well which is not allowing data through
- There is a firewall on the VM its self (windows firewall etc.)
- There is nothing listening on that port

Also, bear in mind that opening the RDP port to any traffic is a bad idea, you will see brute force attack attempts very quickly. I suggest looking at Just in Time VM access, or locking down to specific IP ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your service firstly. You could use `netstat -ant|findstr 7445`. The service should listen on `0.0.0.0` not `127.0.0.1`.

Then, you should check Windows firewall. Open 7445 on firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no antivirus blocking your 7445 port and also inside your VM -> windows firewall add inbound rule for 7445 similar to what you did on Azure.